# Htaccess redirect an URL with lang folder to non lang path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop-1.6

I want to redirect

```
www.mydoman.com/en/page-1.html
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/page-1.html
```

Also

```
www.mydomain.com/fr/page-1.html
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/page-1.html
```

I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ /? [R=301]
```

EDIT
It's working

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

I don't know why Prestashop is not responding with a 404 page in place of showing the new product link.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to restart apache when your using htaccess. What exactly isnt working ?

Comment: I added an answer, but i don't Prestashop is not getting a 404 page in place of showing the new product link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by this

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```